# Pandas> how to find designated str length with regex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1 is like below. I just want to find out and get 'True' value for every rows of df1. but 'False' for every rows of df2.
'True' value is string set of **10~13 length of string set** (only letter and integer.. not a space or other special characters)
'False' value is string set having special characters or space as well.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'component': ['000020421A000', '6594680703C','A0642655U0300','A2155169F1700',
                             'KR77672001','A4844730U0200','KR96080151B','KR99002213','SKRSCT0285','A2C52004804']})



df2 = pd.DataFrame({'component_2': ['R124, R128', 'xasdgkj_sldt ', 'A@C0293847702']})
```

i want to use str.match('regex') but I don't know which regex is appropriate for this case.

Comment: Could you clarify your question please with a sample output of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your question, you are looking for a regex that matches your criteria for *valid* string:

> contains only strings or integers & has length between 10 & 13

```
df1.component.str.match('^[A-Za-z0-9]{10,13}$')
```

would return an array of all `True`. The same on df2 would return all `False`

Answer (score 1):

You want to match a case insensitive character group containing letters and digits, repeated 10 to 13 times. if you allow underscores `_` then you could use `^\w{10,13}$`. as presented the pattern you want is `^[a-z\d]{10,13}$` with a case insensitive flag. or `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,13}$` if you want to be verbose.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'component': ['000020421A000','6594680703C','A0642655U0300','A2155169F1700','KR77672001','A4844730U0200','KR96080151B','KR99002213','SKRSCT0285','A2C52004804']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'component_2': ['R124, R128', 'xasdgkj_sldt ', 'A@C0293847702']})

pattern = re.compile(r"^[a-z\d]{10,13}$", re.IGNORECASE)
print(
    df1.component.str.match(pattern),
    df2.component_2.str.match(pattern),
    sep="\n\n")
```

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
9    True
Name: component, dtype: bool

0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: component_2, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Your attempt is almost correct, however you are missing the start & end anchors. This regex pattern will also match alpha-numeric codes that are greater than 13 characters in length.

Comment: @HaleemurAli oh yea, i missed that part. i have changed my answer to reflect that requirement.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment!! was so useful!!